# How to transfer a state from a component to another?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-hooks, state

I have a form which takes name, age and gender as user input. When the submit button is clicked I want to transfer the state of the form to `App.js` where I can add the state to the array with users. How can I transfer the state from `Form.js` to `App.js`?

```
//Form.js

export const Form = ({ onClick }) => {
  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    name: "william",
    age: 31,
    gender: "male",
  });
  return <div><input type="submit" onClick={onClick}/></div>;
};

//App.js

export const App = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState({
    name: "Anna",
    age: 24,
    gender: "female",
  });

  function addUser(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Form onClick={addUser} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a function down to the form component that takes the new user as an argument:

```
//Form.js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const Form = ({ onClick }) => {
  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    name: "william",
    age: 31,
    gender: "male",
  });
  return <div>
    <input type="submit" onClick={() => onClick(form)}/>
  </div>;
};

//App.js

export const App = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([{
    name: "Anna",
    age: 24,
    gender: "female",
  }]);

  function addUser(newUser) {
    setUsers([...users, newUser]);

  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Form onClick={(newUser) => addUser(newUser)} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

In your onClick you call that function and pass in the new user. This addUser function spreads the users that you already have in the state of App into a new array and then adds the new user to it. Note that you need an array to keep track of multiple users - you just an object before.

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for. How can I for example only add age to users from the form?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean. Do you want to store objects in your App state that only contain a key / value pair for age?

Comment: I mean how can I do the same thing that you did, but with leaving the gender out?

Comment: ```<input type="submit" onClick={() => onClick({ name: form.name, age: form.age })}/>``` This is one way to do it. You put the properties you want into a new object.

Answer (score 0):

ReactJS is a uni-directional framework.

> Unidirectional data flow is a technique that is mainly found in
> functional reactive programming. It is also known as one-way data
> flow, which means the data has one, and only one way to be transferred
> to other parts of the application. In essence, this means child
> components are not able to update the data that is coming from the
> parent component. In React, data coming from a parent is called props

If you are trying to make the data flow, the other way, this is not the right approach and that means there is a better way available.

You can achieve this by `useRef` but while scaling your application , you can run into trouble due to this flaw.

```
/Form.js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const Form = ({ onClick }) => {
  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    name: "william",
    age: 31,
    gender: "male",
  });
  return <div>
    <input type="submit" onClick={() => onClick(form)}/>
  </div>;
};

//App.js

export const App = () => {
const ref = React.createRef();
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([{
    name: "Anna",
    age: 24,
    gender: "female",
  }]);

  function addUser(newUser) {
    setUsers([...users, newUser]);

  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Form ref={ref} onClick={(newUser) => addUser(newUser)} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Now through `ref` you have a reference of the child component in the parent component. You can put any event listener on it and it will work.